# azure PaaS solution provides additional memory to apps by changing pricing tiers

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloud

I'm preparing to pass the AZ-900 certification.

I'm practicing with dump tests, and there's a question where I don't understand the answer.

Can anyone explain why the answer to this question is 'No'?
Question is

> A Platform as a Service (PaaS) solution provides additional memory to
> apps by changing pricing tiers, Yes or No ?'

Answer (score 0):

I Guess the answer to this question is **Yes**, that's correct. In a Platform as a Service (PaaS) solution, you can often scale resources such as memory by changing the pricing tier or service plan. so its a correct statement, all the best for the exam